# Limit of the recursive formula $a[n] = \frac{(x + a[n - 1])^2}{1 + a[n - 1]}$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

The limit of $$a[n] = \frac{(x + a[n - 1])^2}{1 + a[n - 1]}.$$
How would I calculate this, if I only knew the recursive formula? Values that matter for $x$ is $0<x<1$, and even more $0<x<0.5$ (diverges above that. )

This continues on my previous question. Background and motivation, why is this important, I'm working on a game theoretical system. A collusion attack vector scales with $a[n]$. Thanks to previous answer, I understand mathematically where it converges perfectly now (already knew it by simulating it many times over years) but I cannot know how to derive the answer.

Comment: Hello :) This is not an answer. If the sequence converges with limit $a$, we get $a(1+a)=(x+a)^2$. And this is a linear equation in $a$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you, your comment and caverac's answer made me understand it. Very simple, and helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand [Jochen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/950888/jochen)'s comment, *if the sequence converges* then $a_N = a_{N + 1} = \cdots = a$ for a sufficiently large $N$, so this translates to

$$
a = \frac{(x + a)^2}{1 + a}
$$

whose solution is

$$
a = \frac{x^2}{1 - 2x}
$$

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you (and @Jochen). Very helpful.